# How to return the variable itself if it is not None, and if None, return "None"?

Tags: rust

I am trying to do this with a one-liner, or a less ugly and less repetitive way:

```rust
fn class_requirements(current_class: Model) -> String {
    return format!(
        "
        Required Race: {}
        Required Weapon Proficiency: {}
        ",
        match current_class.req_race {
            Some(race) => race,
            None => String::from("None"),
        },
        match current_class.req_weapon_proficiency {
            Some(prof) => prof,
            None => String::from("None"),
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) or [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else) to unwrap an `Option` and substitute an alternate value for the `None` case:

```rust
fn class_requirements(current_class: Model) -> String {
    format!(
        "
        Required Race: {}
        Required Weapon Proficiency: {}
        ",
        current_class.req_race.unwrap_or_else(|| String::from("None")),
        current_class.req_weapon_proficiency.unwrap_or_else(|| String::from("None")),
    )
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=968a5ece6abcf8da5cbb491222c3b3b3)</sup>

You can avoid heap allocating the `String`s by calling [`as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref), which turns an `Option<String>` into an `Option<&str>`. Then `"None"` can be a static string:

```rust
fn class_requirements(current_class: Model) -> String {
    format!(
        "
        Required Race: {}
        Required Weapon Proficiency: {}
        ",
        current_class.req_race.as_deref().unwrap_or("None"),
        current_class.req_weapon_proficiency.as_deref().unwrap_or("None"),
    )
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a83d7dd9b7043f1b51789f9ad27e1e66)</sup>

(It's also good style to remove the [explicit `return`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961879/why-is-using-return-as-the-last-statement-in-a-function-considered-bad-style), which I've done above.)

Answer (score -2):

if you are only dealing with `Option<String>` type then try `.or`

```rust
fn handle_opt_str(o: Option<String>) -> String {
    o.or(Some("None".to_string())).unwrap()
}


fn main() {
    println!("{}", handle_opt_str(Some("hello".to_string()))); // hello
    println!("{}", handle_opt_str(None)); // None
}
```

Comment: Perhaps slightly better: `o.unwrap_or_else(|| "None".to_string())` which combines the unwrapping, and the lazy creation of the default value if it's not `Some`?

Comment: `.or(Some(x)).unwrap()` is just a longer way to write `.unwrap_or(x)`, but the latter is incapable of panicking.